# useEffect stops working after the first time useState's set becomes stale within a timer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, settimeout, create-react-app, use-effect

I essentially want a timer to update a displayed calculated time constantly. If I run the setTimeout faster than the expected time the calculation results in a new number for the time (840ms vs 1000ms), the loop ends forever. How do I make this work with React Hooks? Not looking for the answer of just keeping it at 1000ms. I'm trying to find if my usage of useState and useEffect are incorrect or that there's a better hook that I'm not thinking of.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
function App() {
  const [display, setDisplay] = useState("0");
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("display", display);
    function calculateTime() {
      console.log('timer', Date.now() - 1626712121266);
      return Date.now() - 1626712121266;
    }
    let timeoutId: NodeJS.Timeout;
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("setTimeout")
      setDisplay(displayTime(calculateTime()));
    }, 840);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }
  }, [display]);
  return (
    <>
      {display}
    </>
  );
}
function displayTime(milliseconds: number) {
  const seconds = Math.floor(milliseconds / 1000 % 60);
  const displaySeconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
  let displayString = "" + displaySeconds;
  console.log('displayString', displayString)
  return displayString;
}
export default App;
```

Console results after a refresh. Notice how once seconds stay the same, useEffect stops being called.

[image]

How I created this test:

1. > yarn create react-app test-timer --template typescript
2. Replaced the App() function with what is shown here.

Answer (score 0):

Converting the useState into [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) with setInterval as the timing function did the trick. useReducer is still like a magical black box to me but it works for now without a hitch. Would love an explanation why this is happening.

```
import { useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
function App() {
  function reducer(state: any, action: any): any {
    if (action.type === 'displayUpdate') {
      const display = displayTime(Date.now() - 1626712121266);
      return {
        display: display,
      };
    }
  }

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { display: "0" });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");

    let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("setInterval")
      dispatch({type: 'displayUpdate'});
    }, 500);

    return () => {
      console.log('useEffect return')
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      {state.display}
    </>
  );
}
function displayTime(milliseconds: number) {
  const seconds = Math.floor(milliseconds / 1000 % 60);
  const displaySeconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
  let displayString = "" + displaySeconds;
  console.log('displayString', displayString)
  return displayString;
}
export default App;
```